# Play Animator without a string

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have multiple objects with animator attached in them and they have only one clip but with different strings. Is it possible to play those animators without an anim name?

for example; instead of:

```
animator.Play("NameOfAnimationClip", -1, 0.25f);
```

I want to just do

```
animator.Play("GetTheCurrentString", -1, 0.25f);
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean something like `animator.Play(GetCurrentAnimationString(), -1, 0.25f);` where `GetCurrentAnimationString()` is a function that returns the name of the animation you want to play?

Comment: yes exactly :) i guess that works then.

Comment: I posted a more complete answer based on the comment, with some expansion on the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the previous comment, you can just have a function that returns the name of the animation you want.

```
string GetCurrentAnimation()
{
    //TODO: decide what animation you want to use according to your game logic.
    return _myAnimationString;
}
```

And then just use that function in your Play call

```
animator.Play(GetCurrentAnimation(), -1, 0.25f);
```

Alternatively, you could just declare a string property and use that.

```
private string _myAnimationString = "idle";
...
animator.Play(_myAnimationString, -1, 0.25f);
```

Comment: Sorry but does not work. I still have to enter the animation name :/

Comment: Enter the animation name where?  In the Play call?  No, the function call will provide that.  Please update your question with what you tried that didn't work.

Comment: The function call does not provide it. I used your code itself but the animation is still not playing

Comment: I recommend you look more into how the Unity Animator system works.  The code provided isn't going to "just work" for you; you will have to adapt it for your specific situation.